# jQuery trying to display element inline gives error

Tags: jquery, html, inline

I am trying to display an html element, but it has to have the inline attribute. The second line in my code breaks the html page:

```
$('#add_existing_suggestion').fadeIn(100).show();                                
$('#add_existing_suggestion').css("display":"inline");
```

I saw on this forum that it worked for people: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/fadein-inline

Any way I can make the element get displayed inline?

Thanks!!

Comment: How does it break the page? What happens and what do you want to happen? Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`css` method take two arguments as string or a map containing key/value pair of styles. What you are doing will give a syntax error on the page and will break other js also. Try this

```
$('#add_existing_suggestion').css("display", "inline");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is incorrect. The syntax for .css() is:

```
.css( propertyName )
.css( propertyName, value )
```

Change it to `$('#add_existing_suggestion').css("display", "inline");`